# The translation of "the draft services for suppliers"?

Tags: translation

The meaning of it is like "someone draft some informations for guiding suppliers".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a traslation?

供应商服务草案 is the translation using Google Translator.

@Tang Ho's answer is more exact. 供应商草案服务 is a good translation. If it can be longer, 为供应商提供草案的服务 is even more clear.

Comment: The correct translation is 供应商草案服务, Google is not always reliable